# Excel Match Function Returns Row Outside the Lookup Array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, match, excel-match

I have a problematic application of the `MATCH` function in Microsoft Excel.

I'm quite used to using the `INDEX-MATCH` combo and have never faced an issue like this before.

The problem is that the row number returned by a `MATCH` function is outside the lookup array.

Input data may seem a bit complex:

- Column `A` contains datetimes at 10 minute intervals (Example: 08.03.2016 00:00, 08.03.2016 00:10, 08.03.2016 00:20, dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm).
- Column `B` contains the lookup array, consisting of varying set of values related to each datetime.

The list is long, and column B is not the only result value column, which is why I have created some named ranges too.

The problematic function is:

```
=MATCH(E37;INDEX(MainData;MATCH(E18+E19;DateSelector;0);COLUMN(hex1_cur)):INDEX(MainData;MATCH(E21+E20;DateSelector;0);COLUMN(hex1_cur));1)
```

Where the named ranges are:

- `MainData` = All datetime and result cells, approximately `A4:D2000`.
- `DateSelector` = Datetime cells (dynamic array, acknowledges the amount of cells in Column `A`).
- `hex1_cur` = Identifier for a result column, in this case indicating to Column `B`.

`E18+E19` form starting datetime for evaluation period, and `E21+E20` marks the ending point.

`E37` has the lookup value, and as you can see, I use `match_type 1`, because I want to locate the largest value less than or equal to my lookup.

**Why does the function work for the first evaluation period in screen snip (formula is in `D38`), but not anymore for the next (`E38`)?**

Please note that the **`INDEX-MATCH` array in the lookup array section of the main MATCH search works fine**, so the fault shouldn't be in my named ranges.

I use this exactly same structure also for other purposes in this worksheet, and it's been correct so far.

**So how can the main `MATCH` function in my formula return a row number outside of the `INDEX-MATCH`-restricted lookup array?**

In this test case, the `INDEX-MATCH` lookup array produces accurate location results from row `187` to row `309`, yet the resulting row number is `39`, as in the picture in `E38`.

On contrary, row `61`, the result for `D38` formula, is accurately within its own `INDEX-MATCH`-defined lookup array:

[image: Screen snip showing the result row and location of the formula cells]

My apologies for unclear explanation. Please ask if you didn't understand the situation properly.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion is in your interpretation of the result of the `Match` function. The result is **not** a row number, but a position **relative to** the beginning of the submitted array parameter.

> In this test case, the INDEX-MATCH lookup array produces accurate location results from row 187 to row 309 - yet the resulting row number is 39

The result 39 in this example case means row 225; that is, 39 away from the beginning of the array.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I have had quite an embarrassing misconception of the whole functionality of the match function until now - I guess my earlier applications just had happened to be immune to this phenomenon. Row 225 indeed has the correct value. Awesome!

Comment: @Jaakko yes, previously you only used complete columns, such as `Index(A:A, Match(1, B:B, 0))`. In these cases the two interpretations of the result are the same.